# QtCharts setRange issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to display some data using `QtCharts`. When I set my data then nothing is displayed. I think the problem is with the `setRange` method.

**Code:**

*chart.h:*

```
#ifndef CHART_H
#define CHART_H

#include <QChart>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QAbstractAxis>
#include <QSplineSeries>
#include <QValueAxis>
#include <QDebug>

QT_CHARTS_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QSplineSeries;
class QValueAxis;
QT_CHARTS_END_NAMESPACE

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class Chart: public QChart
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Chart(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags = 0);
    virtual ~Chart();

public slots:
    void handleTimeout();

private:
    QTimer m_timer;
    QSplineSeries *m_series;
    QStringList m_titles;
    QValueAxis *m_axisX;
    QValueAxis *m_axisY;
    qreal m_step;
    qreal m_x;
    qreal m_y;
    QList<double> testList;
};

#endif /* CHART_H */
```

*chart.cpp:*

```
#include "chart.h"

Chart::Chart(QGraphicsItem *parent, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags):
    QChart(QChart::ChartTypeCartesian, parent, wFlags),
    m_series(0),
    m_step(0),
    m_x(1),
    m_y(1)
{
    m_axisX = new QValueAxis(this);
    m_axisX->setLabelsVisible(false);
    m_axisY = new QValueAxis(this);
    m_axisY->setLabelsVisible(false);
    connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Chart::handleTimeout);
    m_timer.setInterval(1000);
    m_series = new QSplineSeries(this);
    QPen green(Qt::green);
    green.setWidth(3);
    m_series->setPen(green);
    m_series->append(m_x, m_y);
    legend()->hide();
    addSeries(m_series);
    setAxisX(m_axisX, m_series);
    setAxisY(m_axisY, m_series);
    m_axisX->setTickCount(5);
    testList << 93.8436 << 777.797 << 2507.78 << 5999.44 << 6806.54 << 7481.16
                 << 8008.5 << 8093.8 << 8161.83 << 8216.99
                 << 8280.46 << 8328.4 << 8394.55 << 8469.84
                 << 8500.65 << 8558.16 << 8660.9 << 8638.87
                 << 8726.47 << 8715.25 << 8804.48 << 8793.86
                 << 8839.42 << 8875.75 << 8938.24 << 8977.09
                 << 9020.27 << 9046.7 << 9092.04 << 9121.58
                 << 9155.36 << 9199.46;
    axisX()->setRange(0, 100);
    axisY()->setRange(-1, 100);
    m_timer.start();
}

void Chart::handleTimeout()
{
    qreal x = plotArea().width() / m_axisX->tickCount();
    qreal y = (m_axisX->max() - m_axisX->min()) / m_axisX->tickCount();
    m_x += y;

    if (!testList.isEmpty()) {
        m_y = testList.first();
        testList.takeFirst();
    }

    qDebug() << "m_x: " << m_x << " " << "m_y: " << m_y;
    m_series->append(m_x, m_y);
    scroll(x, 0);
}

Chart::~Chart()
{

}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "chart.h"
#include <QChartView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    Chart *chart = new Chart;
    //chart->setTitle("Dynamic spline chart");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);
    QChartView chartView(chart);
    chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    chartView.resize(window.size());
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(&chartView);
    window.setLayout(layout);
    window.setMinimumSize(810, 400);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks.

**[Updated]**

I have fixed the issue. Now it works well, but I need to set the axis rect background color.

**Screenshot:**

[image: 1456789.png]

Any ideas how to set the axis background color? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using `QtNetworkMonitor` example from [GitHub](https://github.com/coolshou/qtnetworkmonitor). The issue is resolved.